# Tail recursion: internal "loop" function or default values for accumulators

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I know of at least two styles to writing tail recursive functions. Take a `sum` function for example:

```
def sum1(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def loop(xs: List[Int], acc: Int): Int = xs match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs1 => loop(xs1, acc + x)
  } 
  loop(xs, 0)
}
```

vs

```
def sum2(xs: List[Int], acc: Int = 0): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => acc
  case x :: xs1 => sum2(xs1, x + acc)
}
```

I've noticed the first style (internal loop function) much more commonly than the second. Is there any reason to prefer it or is the difference just a matter of style?

Comment: There are good reasons to avoid default arguments most of the time (see e.g. [this comment](https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover/issues/116#issuecomment-51280344) and the rest of the thread).

Comment: default argument values are relatively recent in scala history, which may explain that form 1 is more common. But there is also the problem of making the extra arguments part of the public interface, which may be strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of reasons to prefer the first notation.

Firstly, you define clearly to your reader what's the internal implementation from the external one.

Secondly, in your example the seed value is a pretty simple one that you can put straight as a default argument, but your seed value may be a very complicated-to-compute object that requires a longer init than default. Should this init for example require to be done asynchronously, you definitely want to put it out of your default value and manage with Futures or w/e.

Lastly, as Didier mentioned, the type of sum1 is a function from List[Int] -> Int (which makes sense), while the type of sum2 is a function from (List[Int], Int) -> Int which is less meaningful. Also, this implies that it's easier to pass sum1 around than sum2. For example, if you have an object that encapsulates a list of Int's and you want to provide synthesizer functions over it you can do (**pseudocode, i dont have a repl to write it properly now**):

```
class MyFancyList[T](val seed: List[T]) = {
  type SyntFunction = (List[T] => Any)

  var functions = Set[SyntFunction]

  def addFunction(f: SyntFunction) = functions += f

  def computeAll = {
    for {
      f <- functions
    } 
    yield {
      f(seed)
    }
  }
}
```

And you can do:

```
def concatStrings(list:List[Int]) = {
  val listOfStrings = for {
    n <- list
  }
  yield {
    n+""
  }
  listOfStrings.mkString
}
val x = MyFancyList(List(1, 2, 3))
x.addFunction(sum1)
x.addFunction(concatStrings)
x.computeAll == List(6, "123")
```

but you can't add sum2 (not as easily at least)